# Doubts about the Einstein "way"

Tags: general-relativity, geodesics, equivalence-principle

I followed the whole Einstein/Schwarzschild derivation, and the very first thing I don't like in it, is that after emphasizing the equivalence-principle requirement, Einstein skips this as a boundary condition, and assumes instead that the Ricci's curvature is div(grad(relativistic potential)); and that its ZERO was sufficient to define this potential!
The "div(grad(potential))=0" sufficiently defines potential only in flat space!
Gravitational acceleration, to be a grad(potential) in curved space, MUST be defined/measured in local (curved) space!
At this point, the analogy: acceleration <-> curvature_of_geodesic; is incorrect because the curvature of geodesic IS defined/calculated in map space.
Is there any method of quantitative comparison between acceleration and gravitational field, and hence, any demonstration that Schwarzschild's solution satisfies the equivalence principle?

Comment: It's hard to read this with this formatting.  Some paragraph breaks and/or formatting the equations in MathJax might help - Though I suspect that, as written, this text will still get close as "non-mainstream". Potentially with a slightly different approach to the question you could avoid that, but, again, hard to tell as it's now written.

Comment: Could you link to, or at least identify, the source in which you found a derivation? More than one exists, but if we know which one you saw we can address your specific doubts.

Comment: Given the amazing answer, we should edit the question to make it acceptable instead of closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from the Schwarzschild  (SM) metric:

$$ds^2 = c^2 dt^2 \left( 1+ \frac{2U}{c^2}\right) - dr^2 \frac{1}{1+ \frac{2U}{c^2}} -r^2 d\Omega^2$$

where $U = -\frac{GM}{r}$ is the scalar potential with $M$ as mass of gravitating body. In the following we can take into account that the ratio of the scalar potential to square of the velocity of light is extraordinarily small for systems where Newton's gravitational law had been checked for its correctness, i.e. systems like the surroundings of the earth or sun. For heavier & smaller objects (white dwarfs, neutron stars, black holes etc.) it's better to use Einstein's gravitation theory right away. So this means that the following approximation would be not valid around these extremely heavy stellar-like objects mentioned above.

$$ \frac{U}{c^2} \approx \begin{cases} 10^{-9} &  \text{on the earth's surface} \\   10^{-6} &\text{on the sun's surface} \\ 10^{-4} &\text{on the surface of a white dwarf}\\
10^{-1} & \text{on the surface of a neutron star}\end{cases}$$

So for instance around the sun $U/c^2 \approx 10^{-6}$, so we are allowed of a couple of approximations. So we will write the SM metric:

$$ds^2 = c^2 dt^2 \left( 1+ \frac{2U}{c^2}\right) - dr^2 (1- \frac{2U}{c^2}) -r^2 d\Omega^2$$

This will also allow us to develop the metric tensor's  components $g_{ik}$ in the following way ($\eta_{ik}=diag(1,-1,-1,-1)$ is the Minkowski tensor)

$$g_{ik} \approx\eta_{ik} + 2\psi_{ik}$$

and as the $\psi_{ik}$ are really small, so we can neglect all terms of order higher than one (i.e. the quadratical terms) in the Ricci-tensor:

$$R_{ik} = \psi_{ik,l}^{\quad l} +\psi^l_{l,ik} - \psi^{l}_{k,li} -\psi^l_{i,kl}$$

Due to some freedom in the choice of coordinates this expression can be further simplified, so at the end we get:

$$R_{ik} =\psi_{ik,l}^{\quad l} \quad \text{or simply }\quad R_{ik} =\Box \psi_{ik}$$

Then starting from Einstein's equations $R_{ik} =\kappa(T_{ik} -\frac{1}{2}g_{ik} T^l_l)$ without any approximation and using the mentioned decomposition of the metric tensor above we get:

$$\Box \psi_{ik} = \kappa (T_{ik} -\frac{1}{2}\eta_{ik} T^l_l)$$.

Considering the Schwarzschild case we can just approximate the energy-momentum tensor like $T_{ik}=diag(\rho c^2,p,p,p)\approx diag(\rho c^2,0,0,0)$ so that $T^l_l = \rho$.
When we assume a massive object there is no pressure or assume that the pressure is much smaller than the energy density $\rho c^2$ so that it can be neglected (the $c^2$ factor makes the first element in the diagonal very large compared to the other elements).

Yes indeed we will limit our approximation to the $00$ component of the $\psi$-tensor, but if desired the other components can also be computed.
We take from the SM-metric $\frac{U}{c^2} =\psi_{00}$. And we get:

$$\Box \psi_{00} = \kappa (T_{00}- \frac{1}{2}\eta_{00} T^l_l) = \frac{\kappa}{2}\rho   = 4\pi \frac{G}{c^2} \rho$$

Under the further assumption that the concerned bodies of the system don't move a lot the time derivative of $\psi_{00}$ is zero we get:

$$\Delta U = 4\pi G \rho$$

Yes in the outer space, i.e. outside the massive body $\rho=0$ and so we get there $\Delta U =0$. This is nothing new, potential theory  from the $19^{th}$ century  already tells us this. Yes this actually corresponds to $R_{ik}=0$. Naively we could conclude in both cases that the field is zero, but this would be only true if the boundary conditions would say $\rho=0$ in the whole space up to infinity in both cases. But for the SM case, this not the case, so in both cases -- the Newton's and Einstein case -- the solution will be non-zero. It is well-known that $\Delta U=0$ is fulfilled by harmonic functions that are non-zero (the latter have to be adapted to the given boundary conditions).  So there is no problem at all.

For the implication of the equivalence principle one has to do a similar computation for the geodesic equation (the dot represents the derivation with the $ds$):

$$ \ddot{x}^i = -\Gamma^i_{kl} \dot{x}^k \dot{x}^l $$

This equation takes the equivalence principle (EP) into account because the mass which should be on the lhs the inertial mass as multiplication factor, whereas on the rhs the gravitational mass as multiplication factor which are actually already cancelled out because both are the same (EP).
We assume here that the velocities of the concerned bodies are small, so we can approximate $\dot{x}^i=(1,0)$. We will now use Greek alphabet indices for space coordinates $\alpha =(1,2,3)$.

$$\frac{d^2 x^\alpha}{ds^2} \approx \frac{d^2 x^\alpha}{c^2 dt^2} = -\Gamma^\alpha_{kl} \frac{dx^k}{ds}\frac{dx^l}{ds} \approx -\Gamma^\alpha_{00}$$

Computing the Christoffel-symbols we get:

$$\Gamma^\alpha_{00} = \psi_{00,\alpha} -2\psi_{0 \alpha,0}$$

Assuming that the gravitational field is stationary we can make an appropiate choice of coordinates where the mixed components ${0,\alpha}$ of the metric (and therefore also $\psi_{0\alpha}$) disappear. We are left with only 1 term on the rhs of the Christoffel symbol computation. So we get for the geodesic equation:

$$ \frac{dx^\alpha}{c^2 dt^2} = -\nabla \psi_{00}$$

i.e. we get the Newton's law:

$$\frac{d^2\vec{x}}{dt^2} = -\nabla U$$

or compared with what you might expect:

$$ m_\text{inertial} \frac{d^2\vec{x}}{dt^2} = - m_G\nabla U$$

One would not get that ($m_G$ is the gravitational mass, $m_\text{inertial}$ the inertial mass) because indeed the EP is used right from the beginning which allows to cancel them out.

So I think, the derivation is solid and the used approximations are valid.
I haven't put the definitions of all symbols of the Ricci tensor, Christoffel symbols etc due to the length of the answer. They can be found on Wikipedia for instance. Or just ask for it.

In case of Einstein's theory there are 10 components of the metric whereas in Newton's theory there is only 1. Using the demonstrated approximation they will also fulfill some equations, but in comparison with the component of $\psi_{00}$ these components  will be much smaller taking into account the table of $U/c^2$ above.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm using principally "Differential Geometry and Relativity  Theory" of R.L.Faber of 1983 (+pdf updated in 2019), and your notation is a bit different... I will work on it to be able to ask my question better. 
Seems not important for the content, but in the third equation from the end should not be the second derivative? I will work also on my editing!